# React.Component Onclick event: Comments.js:189 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeCommentMutation' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I wish to call a function using an onClick event and pass it some parameters from the event, but am receiving the above mentioned error message.

What am I overlooking here?

My code is as follows:

```html
class Comments extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.removeCommentMutation = this.removeCommentMutation.bind(this);
  }
  
  removeCommentMutation (postID, commentID) {
  ....
  }

  handleSubmitError (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }

  renderComment (comments) {
    return (
      <div className="comment" key={comments.id}>
        <p>
          <strong>{comments.user}</strong>
          {comments.text} 
          <button className="remove-comment" onClick={() => this.removeCommentMutation(this.props.postId, comments.id)}>&times;</button>
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
  handleSubmit (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.addCommentMutation(this.props.postId, this.refs.author.value, this.refs.comment.value);
    this.refs.commentForm.reset();
    this.refs.author.focus();
  }

  render () {
    const comments = this.props.post.comments || [];
    const currentPosts = comments.map(this.renderComment);

    return (
      <div className="comments">

        {currentPosts}

        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} ref="commentForm" className="comment-form">
          <input type="text" ref="author" placeholder="author"/>
          <input type="text" ref="comment" placeholder="comment"/>
          <input type="submit" hidden/>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

}
```

The full error is:

```html
Comments.js:189 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeCommentMutation' of undefined
    at onClick (http://localhost:7770/static/bundle.js:36072:30)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.wrapped (http://localhost:7770/static/bundle.js:63526:29)
    at Object.ReactErrorUtils.invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:7770/static/bundle.js:43148:16)
    at executeDispatch (http://localhost:7770/static/bundle.js:70629:21)
    at Object.executeDispatchesInOrder (http://localhost:7770/static/bundle.js:70652:5)
    at executeDispatchesAndRelease (http://localhost:7770/static/bundle.js:7436:22)
    at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (http://localhost:7770/static/bundle.js:7447:10)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at forEachAccumulated (http://localhost:7770/static/bundle.js:44180:9)
    at Object.processEventQueue (http://localhost:7770/static/bundle.js:7652:7)
    at runEventQueueInBatch (http://localhost:7770/static/bundle.js:74532:18)
    at Object.handleTopLevel [as _handleTopLevel] (http://localhost:7770/static/bundle.js:74548:5)
    at handleTopLevelWithoutPath (http://localhost:7770/static/bundle.js:74651:24)
    at handleTopLevelImpl (http://localhost:7770/static/bundle.js:74631:3)
    at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.perform (http://localhost:7770/static/bundle.js:12582:20)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (http://localhost:7770/static/bundle.js:42559:19)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (http://localhost:7770/static/bundle.js:2907:20)
    at dispatchEvent (http://localhost:7770/static/bundle.js:74762:20)
    at HTMLDocument.wrapped (http://localhost:7770/static/bundle.js:63526:29)
```

Comment: Just place `removeCommentMutation` outside of the constructor.

Comment: remove the `() =>` from your onClick handler

Comment: @AmrAly If I remove `() =>` I get an `TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeCommentMutation' of undefined` error message.

Comment: @muratgozel removeCommentMutation is outside of the constructor. Sorry, I missed an `}` to close off the constructor.

Comment: so your handler look like this `onClick={this.removeCommentMutation(this.props.postId, comments.id)}`

Comment: @AmrAly Yes, that's exactly how I have it, and that generates the error message I mentioned.

Comment: Place `const self = this` immediatly after `renderComment (comments) {` and change `this.removeCommentMutation` to `self.removeCommentMutation`

Comment: You need to `bind()` all of your methods in the constructor, not just `removeCommentMutation`. You're calling `this.removeCommentMutation()` within `renderComment()`. Without `bind`ing, the context of `this` is NOT your Component.

Comment: @Dan your the Man! If you put your response as an answer, I'll accept it and vote it up. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `bind` all of your functions. In React, the context of `this` is `undefined`. That is until you use `bind()` to change the context to be your Component.

You can do this one of two ways.

**Using `.bind()`**

```
class Comments extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.removeCommentMutation = this.removeCommentMutation.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmitError = this.handleSubmitError.bind(this);
    this.renderComment = this.renderComment.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  removeCommentMutation (postID, commentID) {
  ....
  }

  handleSubmitError (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }

  renderComment (comments) {
    return (
      <div className="comment" key={comments.id}>
        <p>
          <strong>{comments.user}</strong>
          {comments.text} 
          <button className="remove-comment" onClick={() => this.removeCommentMutation(this.props.postId, comments.id)}>&times;</button>
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
  handleSubmit (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.addCommentMutation(this.props.postId, this.refs.author.value, this.refs.comment.value);
    this.refs.commentForm.reset();
    this.refs.author.focus();
  }

  render () {
    const comments = this.props.post.comments || [];
    const currentPosts = comments.map(this.renderComment);

    return (
      <div className="comments">

        {currentPosts}

        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} ref="commentForm" className="comment-form">
          <input type="text" ref="author" placeholder="author"/>
          <input type="text" ref="comment" placeholder="comment"/>
          <input type="submit" hidden/>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

}
```

**Using Arrow functions - ES6**

Typically the context of `this` in JavaScript is determined by how a function is called. With arrow functions, the context is lexical, meaning that `this` is determined by the outer scope (which in this case is your Comments component).

You can use arrow functions like so, which would mean you don't have to constantly `bind()` every single method.

```
class Comments extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  removeCommentMutation = (postID, commentID) => {
  ....
  }

  handleSubmitError = (err) => {
    console.error(err.message);
  }

  renderComment = (comments) => {
    return (
      <div className="comment" key={comments.id}>
        <p>
          <strong>{comments.user}</strong>
          {comments.text} 
          <button className="remove-comment" onClick={() => this.removeCommentMutation(this.props.postId, comments.id)}>&times;</button>
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.addCommentMutation(this.props.postId, this.refs.author.value, this.refs.comment.value);
    this.refs.commentForm.reset();
    this.refs.author.focus();
  }

  render () {
    const comments = this.props.post.comments || [];
    const currentPosts = comments.map(this.renderComment);

    return (
      <div className="comments">

        {currentPosts}

        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} ref="commentForm" className="comment-form">
          <input type="text" ref="author" placeholder="author"/>
          <input type="text" ref="comment" placeholder="comment"/>
          <input type="submit" hidden/>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

}
```

Notice the `foo = () => {}` syntax. You don't have to do this for Component lifecycle methods e.g. `componentWillMount`, `componentDidMount` and you don't have to do this for `render`.